# txtEmail not declared (VB.Net Express 2013)

Tags: vb.net

Good afternoon

I am working through a self teach tutorial and have had to resort to looking at the answer to an exercise.  However when I type in the solution into the code window I get an error message saying that txtEmail is not declared.  This is the first part of the code

```
Private Sub btnInStr_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnInStr.Click

    Dim email As String
    Dim Chars_to_check As Char

    email = txtEmail.Text

    Chars_to_check = "@"

    TestEmail1(email, Chars_to_check)

End Sub
```

Any guidance appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You need to drop a TextBox onto your form and name it `txtEmail`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a text box control on your window form with a name of txtEmail

Comment: Hi Bjorn-Roger - Thank you, schoolboy error on my part but I would have stared at it for hours and never seen it